# closeOnSelect: false not working in Select2 when using dropdownAdapter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When you select a specific item in the dropdown, custom selection is hidden. Why? In my options I have `closeOnSelect: false;`

Warning! I use `$.fn.select2.amd.require`. 'select2/dropdown/closeOnSelect' Cannot be deleted.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.select2.amd.require([
      "select2/utils",
      "select2/dropdown",
      "select2/dropdown/attachContainer",
      'select2/dropdown/closeOnSelect'
  ], function (Utils, DropdownAdapter, AttachContainer, closeOnSelect) {
      $('select').select2({
          dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(Utils.Decorate(DropdownAdapter, AttachContainer), closeOnSelect),
          closeOnSelect: false
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<div class="select i-select">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">White</option>
    <option value="2">Gray light</option>
    <option value="3">Gray</option>
    <option value="4">Black</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the docs: `Note that this option is only applicable to multi-select controls.` https://select2.org/dropdown#forcing-the-dropdown-to-remain-open-after-selection

Comment: No it works for single selection also check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `closeOnSelect` to false before using it with the following code

```
closeOnSelect= function(){return false;};
```

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.select2.amd.require([
      "select2/utils",
      "select2/dropdown",
      "select2/dropdown/attachContainer",
      'select2/dropdown/closeOnSelect'
  ], function (Utils, DropdownAdapter, AttachContainer, closeOnSelect) {
  
      closeOnSelect= function(){return false;};
      
      $('select').select2({
          dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(Utils.Decorate(DropdownAdapter, AttachContainer), closeOnSelect)
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<div class="select i-select">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">White</option>
    <option value="2">Gray light</option>
    <option value="3">Gray</option>
    <option value="4">Black</option>
  </select>
</div>
```